# copy one field from table to another field in the same table

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I used this query to copy one full column from the same table:

```
UPDATE 'content_type_chapter' 
   SET 'field_chapternumbersort2_value' = 'field_chapternumbersort_value'
```

But I have received this error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''content_type_chapter' SET 'field_chapternumbersort2_value'='field_chapternumber' at line 1

What could be wrong, I'm unable to get it right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just leave the quotes off your field names, otherwise it thinks you are giving it strings

Answer (score 10):

[Single-quotes are for strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html).

Try backticks instead, e.g.:

```
UPDATE 
    `content_type_chapter` 
SET 
    `field_chapternumbersort2_value` = `field_chapternumbersort_value`
```

The backticks aren't strictly necessary, though.

Comment: Just for the record, looks like this answer was first, and also it's more detailed... *cough* accept *cough*